# Upload a photo from a form at the end of a callback in app.post

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, multer, m

i'm building a server with express. in my html I have a registration form with text fields and a file type input to upload a photo. Server side I manage everything with an app.post which takes care of verifying the data entered and sending the confirmation email. My problem lies in uploading the photo because to do so I use update.single which, being a middleware, is executed before the callback, while I would like to upload the photo only if the data pass the checks contained in the function

```javascript
app.post("/html/autentication/signin.html?", upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    connection.query(`insert into utenti (name, surname, email, pass, regstat) values ("${req.body.name}", "${req.body.surname}", "${req.body.mail}", "${req.body.password}", 0)`, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            connection.query(`select id_user from utenti order by id_user DESC limit 1`, (error, result) => {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                var num
                if (result[0] == undefined) {
                    num = 1
                } else {
                    num = Number(result[0].id_user) +1
                }
            });
            res.sendFile(/*it works*/)
        } else {
            connection.query(`select id_user from utenti order by id_user DESC limit 1`, (error, result) => {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                const testmail = {/* testmail it works*/
                    }
                transport.sendMail(testmail, (err, info) => {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    } else {
                        console.log(info)
                        res.sendFile(/*it works*/)
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    });
})
```